# (R) Question regarding type coercion when converting a data frame to a matrix in R

Tags: r, coercion, type-coercion

apologies for the rather rudimentary questions, but I haven't been able to easily find any answers, and also just want some solid confirmation on things.

I have a data frame which contains numeric, factor and ordered factor variables, and when I converted this to a matrix using as.matrix, I noted that the elements of the matrix were all characters. From this experience, I have 2 questions;

First, am I right in saying that vectors and matrices can only contain one data type, and this is why coercion occurs?

Secondly, and more importantly, what combinations of data types in a data frame lead to character matrices vs. numeric matrices etc? e.g. If I had just logical, integer and numeric types in my df, I imagine I would get a numeric matrix, is this correct? So is it just the inclusion of factors, ordered factors and/or characters in my data frame that, when converted into a matrix, brings about the coercion of every element into a character?

Thanks so much for reading, any help is appreciated :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question: yes and no.

Actually, a matrix is a vector with a `dim` attribute.

And a vector must *usually* have one data type only. A `list` is an exception: it's a `vector` with `list` mode, and a list may also have a `dim` attribute.

For instance:

```
> is.vector(list(1, "a", T))
[1] TRUE

> mode(list(1, "a", T))
[1] "list"

> a <- structure(list(1, "a", T, 1+2i), dim = c(2, 2))
> is.matrix(a)
[1] TRUE

> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    TRUE
[2,] "a"  1+2i
```

But it's still probably the reason `as.matrix` is doing coercion: it's much easier to convert everything to a single type and deal with a matrix with elements of a single type.

However, it's a *choice* made by `as.matrix`, and it would be possible, though I think unadvisable, to convert a data.frame to a list-matrix, while keeping all data types intact.

It would be inefficient: vectors can be stored in contiguous memory locations, which means 1/ no memory wasted in storing element data types, and 2/ faster processing with vectorized code 3/ external C or Fortran code expects contiguous data types, and it would be cumbersome and useless to deal with lists. I have never seen a list-matrix actually used, though I guess it might help in some circumstances.

---

The answer to your second question is in the documentation of `as.matrix`:

> as.matrix is a generic function. The method for data frames will
> return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and any
> non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying as.vector to factors
> and format to other non-character columns. Otherwise, the usual
> coercion hierarchy (logical < integer < double < complex) will be
> used, e.g., all-logical data frames will be coerced to a logical
> matrix, mixed logical-integer will give a integer matrix, etc.

You may also have a look at the source code of `as.matrix.data.frame`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your very readable answer Jean-Claude !! You can probably tell that I'm pretty new to programming, and I've been finding the concept of data types the hardest to grasp so far.

Comment: @v_Apery To learn about them, a good way is to test, for a given object `x`, the result of a few functions: `typeof(x)`, `mode(x)`, `class(x)`, `is.vector(x)`, `is.atomic(x)`, `attributes(x)`, `unclass(x)`, `str(x)`. I'll let you have a look in the documentation about these functions. Note also that for a given `type`, there is often a function `is.type` (for instance, `is.integer`, `is.numeric`, `is.character`...) that returns true if the object passed as argument has this type.